# Filter products by attribute

Tags: django, satchmo

I'm working on an eshop with Satchmo framework.
Does anyone know what steps should i follow  in order to filter products according to a custom attribute(type of material) in order to present the products that have the same kind of material in a page(material.html)?
Should i make a material_view function
Should i override get_absolute_url function?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this without touching the core code, I would make a local app localsite/product  and in models.py:

```
class Material(models.Model):
    product = models.ManyToManyField(Product, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(_("Name"), max_length=30)
    slug = models.SlugField(_("Slug"), help_text=_("Used for URLs, auto-generated from name if blank"), blank=True, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(_("Description"), blank=True, help_text="Optional")
```

Add this new app to your admin, and to additionally make them available from the product page, add them as inline:

```
# if you have lots of products, use the nice horizontal filter from django's admin
class MaterialAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    filter_horizontal = ('product',)

class Material_Inline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Material.product.through
    extra = 1 

admin.site.register(Material, MaterialAdmin)

# Add material to the inlines (needs: from product.admin import Product, ProductOptions)
ProductOptions.inlines.append(Material_Inline)
admin.site.unregister(Product)
admin.site.register(Product, ProductOptions)
```

Then you can adapt your views/urls:

```
# urls.py
url(r'^material-list/([\w-]+)/$', material_list, {}, name="material_list"),

# view.py
def material_list(request, slug):
    products = Product.objects.filter(material__slug='slug')
    return render_to_response('localsite/material/list.html', {'products':products}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: andzep I love you. I was going into satchmo customization madness but this answer made it in 30 minutes !

Comment: Glad this was usefull for you. Yes, after my first project on satchmo I found out, that on 99.99% of the cases, you will always find a nice, small, solution without touching the core. But the problem lies mostly on finding the "how the heck" :-)

Answer (score 0):

When you say "custom attribute" do you mean that you have modified the `product.models.Product` code to add another field?

If that is the case you'll probably want to create a custom view.

If your Product code is something like...

```
class Product(models.Model):
    ...
    matieral_type = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    ...
```

...then you can build a view like this...

```
def material(request,material_type):
    prods = Product.objects.filter(material_type=material_type)
    return render_to_response('material.html',{'products',prods},RequestContext(request))
```